# Instagram link needs to be added to footer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, footer, social-networking, instagram

Stack Overflow recently launched an Instagram account:

> This morning, we launched an Instagram account. We’ve had accounts on Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, and Youtube for a while, but never Instagram. We felt it would be fun to join this visual medium where we could highlight great contributions from our community.
>
> https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/27/stack-overflow-instagram-account/

However there is no Instagram link at the bottom of each site, as there are for the other Stack Exchange social media accounts:

[image: Stack Overflow footer]
[image]

Comment: Context: [We're launching an Instagram account - Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/27/stack-overflow-instagram-account/)

Comment: I'd be interested to hear from TPTB what the actual click-through rate on those existing links are. My gut instinct is that it's in the high zeroes daily

Comment: @Richard TPTB = ? ; I can't find it at [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms).

Comment: @Zera - The Powers That Be. Thems that is in charge of things.

Comment: Voting to leave this open - the link has been added but this question just wasn't marked [tag:status-completed] yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Instagram account](https://www.instagram.com/thestackoverflow) is added to the footer of all the Stack Exchange sites.

**Screenshot from Meta Stack Exchange:**

> [image: MSE]

**Screenshot from Stack Overflow:**

> [image: SO]